# Using ACF and PACF with non-stationary time series

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, stationarity, acf-pacf

I have just started using ARIMA modelling for time-series. I have read that ACF and PACF can be used to determine AR and MA coefficients. As rule of thumb, if ACF has negative value at lag = 1, MA is preferred to AR, and depending on where PACF drops, we can determine `q` and `p` values. However, I am a bit confused how to use ACF and PACF for non-stationary time series.
If the series becomes stationary after 1st order differentiation, `d = 1`. But, should the ACF and PACF be plotted using the original or the stationary (i.e. differentiated) time series? I have found different examples (using [differentiated data example](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/) and [original data example](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/)).
What is the best/correct approach?

Comment: Hi: you should look at the acf and pacf of the stationary series because they don't have meaning in the non-stationary case.  The arima framework allows you to model the stationary series and then convert back afterwards if you need to.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was surprised when a popular page like machinelearningmastery.com didn't use this approach!

Comment: Doubts have been raised if the classical "rules" for using AR and MA to determine the order really work with real world data, particularly when there are both MA and AR. You can always try auto.arima :) or tools like MINIC developed by researchers. But the point by mlofton is certain. Don't use acf and pacf with non stationary data.